# PL/SQL function that takes whole column as an argument

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I need to write a PL/SQL function that calculates a value that depends on all the elements in a column.

For example, suppose I have a column X with numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. I want to write a function that takes this column as an argument and returns maximum values, so that

`SELECT FUN(X) FROM SOME_TABLE`

returns a column with values 5, 5, 5, 5, 5.

Approaching this in a straightforward manner one could write smth like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MMMAX (X NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  Y NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(X) INTO Y FROM DUAL;
  RETURN Y;
END;
```

Such a function will not use the whole column as an argument though. In this example it will sequentially apply MAX(X) to each row of X instead of finding maximum over whole column X.

So, how can I write a function that calculates and returns a value based on the whole column X and not sequentially on its rows?

Comment: write your expected output, there is no such  'column as an argument' thing

Comment: Hmm, well you could try to pass the schema, table and column name to the function. Then, using dynamic SQL, you could build a query, that gets you all the values, so that you can do your calculations on it. Could get pretty messy though.

Comment: You can write an aggregate or analytic function, for example http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/avg-and-sum-for-intervals.html defines `sum_dsinterval()` which gives the sum of an `interval` column. Is that the kind of thing you want?

Answer (score 4):

Huh, I'm not sure I understood what you are saying, especially as it appears that function's parameter is of a `NUMBER` datatype.

I *think* that you want to pass column name (which means that parameter's datatype should be `VARCHAR2`) and get its `MAX` value from some table (which is not to be passed as a parameter). If that's so, dynamic SQL might help. Here's an example based on Scott's schema:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_max (par_column_name in varchar2)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    l_out varchar2(200);
  5  begin
  6    execute immediate 'select max(' || par_column_name ||
  7                      ') from emp' into l_out;
  8    return l_out;
  9  end;
 10  /

Function created.
```

Testing on this sample data:

```
SQL> select deptno, ename, sal from emp;

    DEPTNO ENAME             SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
        20 SMITH             800
        30 ALLEN            1600
        30 WARD             1250
        20 JONES            2975
        30 MARTIN           1250
        30 BLAKE            2850
        10 CLARK            2450
        10 KING             5000
        30 TURNER           1500
        30 JAMES             950
        20 FORD             3000
        10 MILLER           1300
        20 SCOTT            3000
        20 ADAMS            1100

14 rows selected.
```

Function results:

```
SQL> select f_max('deptno') result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------
30

SQL> select f_max('ename')  result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------
WARD

SQL> select f_max('sal')    result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------
5000

SQL>
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to aggregate then you could use the max window/analytic function to return for each row the overall max value:-

```
select max (x) over (partition by null) from some_table
```

Which in your example would return 5,5,5,5,5

Not sure why you want a PL/SQL call (and context switch) though?